Why won't Lucene.NET use an analyzer when querying?
I wrote a custom Analyzer for Lucene.Net 4.8. What I've found is that explicitly set queries fail, but parsed queries succeed, because -- it seems -- parsed queries are also subject to the same analyzer that indexed the document.
Consider an index with one document containing the word awesome in a field name text.
I add this using my custom analyzer, and a token filter (Porter Stemmer) actually indexes it as awesom
So, this fails to return anything.
var query = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "awesome"));

However, this returns the document:
var parser = new QueryParser(MY_VERSION, "text", new MyCustomAnalzyer());
var query = parser.Parse("awesome");

Since the parse is created using my analyzer, I assume my analyzer is also stemming awesome to awesom.
I've also tried this with the term cat. In that case, both versions succeed, because cat doesn't stem at all, so query matches index.
It seems that the parsed version sends the text through the same analyzer that the document went through. However, when I do the query explicitly, it doesn't use the analyzer.
I didn't seem to have this problem in v3. What am I doing wrong? How can I make my explicit queries respect the same analyzer than the indexer uses? Do I need to manually send them through the analyzer when setting up the query?

I think you have answered your own question: Yes, you should typically use the same analyzer when querying as you do when indexing, for the reasons you state. There are exceptions to this guideline - see the "Indexing Analysis vs. Search Analysis" section on this documentation page.

As an aside, I'm surprised that you "didn't seem to have this problem in v3" - but perhaps there were changes affecting the default behavior. These are relatively old versions of Lucene we are talking about, at this point in time.


Why won't Lucene.NET use an analyzer when querying?

It does when you use query parser or query builder like this:
QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder(new MyCustomAnalzyer());
var term = new Term("text", "awesome");
var query = builder.NewTermQuery(Term term);


I didn't seem to have this problem in v3. What am I doing wrong?

This might not be true. It worked in v3 the same ways as v4.8.

How can I make my explicit queries respect the same analyzer than the
indexer uses?

You have to use QueryBuilder

Do I need to manually send them through the analyzer when setting up
the query?

Obviously, yes. Otherwise you will get mess like you described.
